# Groupby by a column and select specific value from other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Input dataframe:

```
+-------------------------------+
|ID        Owns_car    owns_bike|
+-------------------------------+
| 1          1               0  |
| 5          1               0  |
| 7          0               1  |
| 1          1               0  |
| 4          1               0  |
| 5          0               1  |
| 7          0               1  |
+-------------------------------+


Expected Output: 
+------------------------------+
|ID       Owns_car    owns_bike|
+------------------------------+
| 1          1               0 |
| 5          1               1 |
| 7          0               1 |
| 4          1               0 |
+------------------------------+
```

Grouping by ID and then selecting value '1' over 0 for the other columns. Checking if for a given ID the person owns a car and bike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'max' after your groupby to select the max value (which will prefer 1 over 0)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 5, 7, 1, 4, 5, 7],
                   'Owns_car': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                   'owns_bike': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
df.groupby('ID').max().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey, @edhaussy thanks for the answer, but what if there are other columns along with above mentioned, and I want those other columns as it is, without application of 'max' operation. Any Idea on how to achieve it??

Comment: you could use 'agg' function to apply different operations for each columns you want to keep


`df.groupby('ID').agg({'Owns_car': 'max', 'owns_bike': 'max'})`

Comment: What if I want to keep another column as it is without applying any operation, how to keep a column in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform` with `max` and then remove duplicates by `ID`

```
df[['Owns_car', 'owns_bike']] = df.groupby('ID')[['Owns_car', 'owns_bike']].transform('max')

df = df.drop_duplicates('ID')
```